# p:inputText onkeyup when delete last char

Tags: jsf, primefaces

when on p:iputText delete the last character and field is empty, onkeyup event does not fire.
Same if I use p: ajax event and keyup.
Any solution?

```
<p:inputText id="nome" value="#{pdasController.nome}" size="30">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{pdasController.reload}" process="@this" update="tableId, filterPanel"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: What PrimeFaces version are you using? I tried this on PF4.0 and PF5.0 and it worked both times. 
You can get the new value with: 
`public void reload(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
System.out.println((String((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue());
}`

Comment: using PF5. ajax event not called when delete last char. example: input : test (event fire 4 times) -> delete 4 char -> event fire 3 times. last delete not fire event.

Comment: maybe post your backing bean here?

Comment: backbean it is useless to put it. is not called! public void reload() {
  
  System.out.println("fire");
}